# Implicit Intent not being called

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, implicit

I am trying to use Implicit intent to launch an activity within the same application and for an activity of another application(my other application, not the native one), but couldn't succeed in any of the cases.

Here is my sample code for the first part (i.e. to launch an activity within the same application):

**Inside Activity TESTActivity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.myapp.game.myimplicit_action");
startActivity(intent);
```

and here is my manifest file declaration for some activity say 'ImplicitActivity' with the same action:

```
<activity
   android:name=".TESTActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name" >
   <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity  android:name=".ImplicitActivity">
   <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.myapp.test.myimplicit_action" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Both the activities `TESTActivity` and `ImplicitActivity` are in the same application under same package. Still my `ImplicitActivity` activity is not getting called.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. Posting the answer for the others facing the same problem.

We need to add **Default Category** in order to make Implicit intents work. So here is the correct manifest entry for the same activity :

```
<activity
   android:name=".TESTActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name" >
   <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity  android:name=".ImplicitActivity">
   <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.myapp.test.myimplicit_action" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```